# Private chat with flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm developing a webapp for a personal assistant. While a user is connected to the site, I want them to be able to subscribe to their personal notifications while they're online. I went about doing this with socketio and flask socketio and I *thought* that I could just use multithreading, like so:

```
def update_loop():
    while my_update_condition:
        if my_update_exists:
            socketio.emit("update", my_update)

@socketio.on("get_updates")
def get_updates(data):
    '''Websocket thread for getting updates'''
    socketio.emit("debug", {"value": "Starting update loop"})
    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_loop)
    update_thread.start()
```

But my code using this strategy gives any update to all users online. Using flask socketio, how can I securely implement a private chat? The data in the updates isn't ultra-sensitive, but, since it's notifications that the user sets, it's usually personal. Thanks.
Note: In my research on this I came upon something using a `socketid` to send a message just to a specific sender, but I couldn't find an example implementation of this using flask-socketio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `socketio.emit()` function broadcasts to all users by default. To address a message to a single user, you have to set the room to the desired user's room, which is named after the session id of the user. Here is an example:

```
def update_loop(sid):
    while my_update_condition:
        if my_update_exists:
            socketio.emit("update", my_update, room=sid)

@socketio.on("get_updates")
def get_updates(data):
    '''Websocket thread for getting updates'''
    socketio.emit("debug", {"value": "Starting update loop"})
    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=update_loop, args=(request.sid,))
    update_thread.start()
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I wasn't sure if it was secure. Couldn't any unauthenticated user connect to that room?

Comment: Clients cannot connect to any rooms by themselves, it is the server that assigns clients to rooms.